# asp.net mvc 5 role based security

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to implement users-role-permission in asp.net mvc 5.0? Below mentioned article has implemented it in asp.net core. I want to implement the same in asp.net mvc 5.0. Is it doable? please advice
https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/a-better-way-to-handle-authorization-in-asp-net-core/#how-do-i-turn-
the-roles-into-a-permissions-claim
https://github.com/JonPSmith/PermissionAccessControl

Comment: ASP.NET MVC belongs to. Net framework and ASP.NET Core MVC belongs to. Net core. Net framework and. Net core have little difference in syntax, so they can be connected seamlessly. The basic design concept is MVC. There is a little difference with their design mechanism, and their ideas are different. But the basic development methods and methods are the same.

Comment: It's [different](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/choose-aspnet-framework?view=aspnetcore-3.1). So there is no need to implement in asp.net core. There is [role based authorization in Asp.net mvc 5](https://www.google.com/search?q=Role+Based+Authentication+In+ASP.NET+MVC&oq=Role+Based+Authentication+In+ASP.NET+MVC).